# How to Generate a Random Number, Which is an Element of Zn (Partially Blind Signature Program)

Tags: java, encryption, random, rsa, digital-signature

I am trying to implement a partially blind signature scheme in Java from a [paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i1xAFzpE6NpxV6SVVu90-0KSnzPihvx0/view?usp=sharing). In equation (1), it requires two random elements `r` and `u` to be generated, which must be an element of `Zn`.

`r, u ∈ Zn`

This is in an RSA scheme where the modulus `n =  p.q`.

I am not entirely sure how this may be achieved - do I just need to generate a random number, which is not divisible by `p` nor `q`? I assume this could be done using `BigInteger` `gcd`, but I am not sure this is correct.

So far, the parameters I have generated are as follows (with `e` being a `BigInteger` with a value of 3):

```
        do {
            p = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength, rnd);
            q = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength, rnd);

            n = p.multiply(q);
            phi = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
        } while (phi.gcd(e).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0);

        d = e.modInverse(phi);
```

I do not believe the value of `phi` is relevant to this question, it is just part of my RSA parameter generation.

Ideally, there would be a library that can handle said generation of `r, u` for me, but I have been unsuccessful finding any.

Comment: Define your terminology within the question.  Your question should be self-contained, people shouldn't have to go to an external link to find out what you're asking.

Comment: @pjs I have added some more info, I think this should help.

Comment: I suspect you want something like the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Encryption).  It's been decades since I've looked at this stuff, so I'm throwing you a pointer rather than an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fairly easy to devise an easy and fast algorithm to generate a random element of `Zn`:

```
public BigInteger getBiasedRandomModN(BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger r = new BigInteger(n.bitLength(), new SecureRandom());
    return r.mod(n);
}
```

The problem with this code is that it is biased. `BigInteger` only allows us to generate random numbers based on the bit length. If we only generate `r` based on a bit less than that of `n`, some values of `Zn` cannot be reached. If we simply use all of the bits of `n` but take the mod (as shown in the code) the low values of `r` will appear more often.

The way to solve that is to generate `r` so often until it is appears within the bounds of `n`:

```
public BigInteger getRandomModN(BigInteger n) {
    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
    BigInteger r;
    do {
        r = new BigInteger(n.bitLength(), rnd);
    } while (r.compareTo(n) >= 0);
    return r;
}
```

Keep in mind that this code might run very long if `n` is slightly higher than a power of 2. It is best to choose `p` and `q` in a certain way that this doesn't happen.

Comment: This code might contain an off by one error regarding `bitLength` vs `bitCount`. I haven't tested it.