# Is there a way to hash the following hash functions h1 : G1 → Z ∗ q , h2 : {0, 1}∗ → Z ∗ q using some Standard algorithm?

Tags: hash, sha, elliptic-curve

Given that G1 is elliptical curve group and q is prime no. Here elements of G1 will be of form (X,y) coordinates

h1 : G1 → Z ∗ q

h2 : {0, 1}∗ → Z ∗ q

How should the sha algorithm be modified to use for the above hash functions which are collision resistant as well?

Comment: Sha algorithm calculates hash of string to  some fixed length string. So how to modify that algo?

Comment: Since it is easy to serialize an element of G1 or {0,1}* for hashing, the real question is how to create an element of Zq without a bias.

Comment: Here you can see a Java implementation of what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233365/1816580